# How can a run a http request and get response in an Android Widget (SDK 29+)

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm building a simple information display widget. All the offline stuff works OK. How can I process an asynchronous web request. (I can process one fine in a normal activity)

I'm trying to use a Handler, based on another stackoverflow answer, but the widget hangs without any obvious error.

I've simplified my code as much as I can to make it easier to post, and it is using a simple bitcoin price index that is available to anyone, as a simple test scenario (my application will be more complex)

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="co.uk.kicktechnic.lcdclockwidget">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"><!--android:theme="@style/Theme.LCDClockWidget"-->

        <activity
            android:name="uk.co.kicktechnic.lcdclockwidget.LCDClockWidgetGrantSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_initial_grant_settings">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name="uk.co.kicktechnic.lcdclockwidget.LCDClockWidget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/l_c_d_clock_widget_info" />
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name="uk.co.kicktechnic.lcdclockwidget.LCDClockWidgetConfigureActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Code:

```
public class LCDClockWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.l_c_d_clock_widget);
        //views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_sun, String.valueOf(appWidgetId)); //original - show widget ID

        Intent intentUpdate = new Intent(context, LCDClockWidget.class);
        intentUpdate.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

        views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_moon, "set in updateAppWidget");
        
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.l_c_d_clock_widget);

            loadBTC(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_moon, "set in onUpdate");
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }
    
    static void loadBTC(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        try {
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
                    .build();
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error during BPI loading : "
                            + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call call, Response response)
                        throws IOException {
                    final String body = response.body().string();

                    //original code - works in a normal activity
                    //runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    //    @Override
                    //    public void run() {
                    //        parseBpiResponse(body, context);
                    //    }
                    //});

                    //based on a stackoverflow answer
                    Handler mHandler = new Handler();
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
                        public void run() {
                            parseBpiResponse(body, context);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    static void parseBpiResponse(String body, Context context) {
        try {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.l_c_d_clock_widget);

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(body);
            //JSONObject timeObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("time");
            //builder.append(timeObject.getString("updated")).append("\n\n");

            JSONObject bpiObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("bpi");
            JSONObject usdObject = bpiObject.getJSONObject("USD");
            builder.append("$ ").append(usdObject.getString("rate")).append("\n");

            JSONObject gbpObject = bpiObject.getJSONObject("GBP");
            builder.append("£ ").append(gbpObject.getString("rate")).append("\n");

            JSONObject euroObject = bpiObject.getJSONObject("EUR");
            builder.append("€ ").append(euroObject.getString("rate")).append("\n");

            views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_btc, builder.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

Following the advice and using the article: https://medium.com/@sambhaji2134/jobintentservice-android-example-7f58bd2720bf

I've added this (and removed any web/BTC stuff for now)

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Widget has been updated! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mServiceResultReceiver = new BTCServiceResultReceiver(new Handler());
        mServiceResultReceiver.setReceiver((BTCServiceResultReceiver.Receiver) this);
        showDataFromBackground(context, mServiceResultReceiver);
    }
}

public void showData(String data, Context context) {
    //mTextView.setText(String.format("%s\n%s", mTextView.getText(), data));

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.l_c_d_clock_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_btc, data);
}

public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData, Context context) {
    final int SHOW_RESULT = 123;

    switch (resultCode) {
        case SHOW_RESULT:
            if (resultData != null) {
                showData(resultData.getString("data"), context);
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

My hacked together ServiceResultReciever and JobIntentService is pretty much as per the article:

```
public class BTCServiceResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
private Receiver mReceiver;

/**
 * Create a new ResultReceive to receive results.  Your
 * {@link #onReceiveResult} method will be called from the thread running
 * <var>handler</var> if given, or from an arbitrary thread if null.
 *
 * @param handler the handler object
 */

public BTCServiceResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
    super(handler);
}

public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
    mReceiver = receiver;
}

@Override
protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
    if (mReceiver != null) {
        mReceiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
    }
}

public interface Receiver {
    void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
}
}


public class BTCJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
private static final String TAG = JobService.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String RECEIVER = "receiver";
public static final int SHOW_RESULT = 123;
/**
 * Result receiver object to send results
 */
private ResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
/**
 * Unique job ID for this service.
 */
static final int DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID = 1000;
/**
 * Actions download
 */
private static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD = "action.DOWNLOAD_DATA";

static void enqueueWork(Context context, BTCServiceResultReceiver workerResultReceiver) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, JobService.class);
    intent.putExtra(RECEIVER, workerResultReceiver);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DOWNLOAD);
    enqueueWork(context, JobService.class, DOWNLOAD_JOB_ID, intent);
}

@Override
protected void onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent) {
    // We have received work to do.  The system or framework is already
    // holding a wake lock for us at this point, so we can just go.
    Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Executing work: " + intent);
    String label = intent.getStringExtra("label");
    if (label == null) {
        label = intent.toString();
    }
    toast("Executing: " + label);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Running service " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    Log.i("SimpleJobIntentService", "Completed service @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    toast("All work complete");
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// Helper for showing tests
void toast(final CharSequence text) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(BTCJobIntentService.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to do the work in a background thread, but there is no guarantee that your work will complete before your process terminates.

More importantly, you are updating `views` in `parseBpiResponse()` well after your `updateAppWidget()` call. You start the network I/O but then immediately do `updateAppWidget()`, and so your changes to `views` occur too late.

At minimum, you need to `updateAppWidget()` in `parseBpiResponse()` as well.

Better yet would be to have `onUpdate()` move all of this logic into [a `JobIntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/app/JobIntentService), so your process is more likely to stick around long enough to complete the network I/O and request the update to the app widget.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. I think I need a bit of hand-holding, as trying to do this leads to the same issue of the widget hanging with no error. I've followed an example - https://medium.com/@sambhaji2134/jobintentservice-android-example-7f58bd2720bf - but as this isn't for a widget either, I'm in a bit of a mess. See EDIT. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkEMarkEMark: I do not know what "hanging" means in this context, sorry.

Comment: The widget only gets the initial setting of the text, and no longer responds to a manual update button that is in there. I think I need sample code of the simplest widget calling the simplest web service. I can't find any anywhere, despite my best Googling :-(

Comment: @MarkEMarkEMark: Sorry, I do not have a modern app widget example, let alone one involving network I/O. That's on my list for 2021 sometime.